# Visual Studio 2010 Project on shared folder: fatal error C1033: cannot open program database

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I am running Windows 7 inside VMWare on a Mac as I am working on a cross plattform project. I want to keep all my plattform independent files in the same folder - that's why I want to organize everything in a folder on the mac and share it with windows that's running in the VM.
When I try to compile the project in the shared folder, I get
fatal error C1033: cannot open program database '\vmware-host\shared folders\audio\vst3 sdk\base\win\win32\debug.base_vc9\base_vc9.pdb'

I am able to write and read files on that folder using the windows explorer. Did try to run Visual Studio as administrator. Didn't help.

If I just copy my folder from the shared folder to the local drive I am able to compile the project without any problems. But it's not an option to copy my whole project just to make a windows build.

Does anyone have a clue what's going on? How do I get around this?

**Update:** I disabled my antivirus in Windows: Didn't help.
However, a colleague from work pointed me to a workaround: Setup SMB File Sharing under Mac os and connect to the samba share with windows. Surprisingly I am able to compile the project on the samba share. Would be glad if anyone could explain that issue though.

Comment: Maybe related to [this problem](http://spininfo.homelinux.com/news/VMware_Fusion/2011/01/10/Save_a_document_from_MS_Office_to_shared_folder_on_FAT_formatted_partition_) of saving an Office document to a shared folder (although Notepad is said to be able to do it)...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compilation fails randomly: "cannot open program database"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126751/compilation-fails-randomly-cannot-open-program-database)

Comment: Same error when using a VBox shared folder between a Win7 host and WinXP guest. Moving the source code folder out of the virtual shared folder resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly this issue has resolved itself after upgrading to the latest releases and updates (Mavericks, VMWare Fusion, VS 2010). Until then the workaround mentioned in the question just worked fine, and I haven't had a real chance to look at that project again within the last 2 years.

Answer (score 1):

Switch the debug info to C7 format instead of using the PDB.

Project Options -> C/C++ -> General -> Debug Information Format and set it to C7.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick for me. My issue was related to a project located on Gdrive.

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted VS 2010, killed process mspdbsrv.exe, deleted /Debug and rebuilt the project.
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/507155/cl-fatal-error-c1033-cannot-open-program-database

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but instead of a share folder i just could not build even a fresh created solution from a single simple cpp file.

I've noticed, that the devenv.exe was on "Windows XP SP3 Compatability Mode" enabled from here (right mouse button on the file in window explorer, Options, Compatability Pane):

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

I did remove the flag and it has fixed.