# Why do I get the error C1033: cannot open program database in VS 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

After a long break from C++, I am trying to compile a very simple C++ project in VS2010. I created a Win32 C++ console empty project, I selected No precompiled headers and no other MS libraries. I added the following main.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
  string name;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile I get the infamous error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TestGetline, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>main.cpp : fatal error C1033: cannot open program database ''
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Here are a some facts:

- I am running Windows 7 64 bit as VM with Desktop Parallels: Version  6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601. The VM has the Shared Profile checked, which means that the Documents, Downloads etc. folders are shared between OSX & Windows 7.
- VS 2010 version: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel, Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.0.30319 SP1Rel
- The link that I am using to launch VS 2010 has the Run this program in compatibility mode for Windows XP (Service Pack 3) checked. The Run this program as an administrator is not checked.
- I tried a few things suggested in other posts and none of them worked. I tried, for instance, to kill the mspdbsrv.exe (VS 2010 was closed), remove the debug directories by hand, and then recompile the project.  I tried to change the Debug Information Format to C7 compatible but then I get another error (main.cpp : fatal error C1074: 'IDB' is illegal extension for PDB file:). I tried to run VS 2010 as administrator but the error is as stubborn as a bedbug. And yes, there was antivirus running while trying all this.

Any other ideas? One cannot help to wonder if there is anyone at all doing C++ development in VS 2010. Upgrading to VS 2012 or 2013 is not an option at this time.

Thanks

Just an update, here is the output of the build task that fails from the compilation log file:

```
 1>Target "ClCompile" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Targets" from project "C:\projects\cpp\TestGetLine\TestGetline\TestGetline.vcxproj" (target "_ClCompile" depends on it):
   Using "Delete" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
   Task "Delete"
   Done executing task "Delete".
   Task "CL" skipped, due to false condition; ('%(ClCompile.PrecompiledHeader)' == 'Create' and '%(ClCompile.ExcludedFromBuild)'!='true') was evaluated as ('' == 'Create' and ''!='true').
   Using "CL" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.CppTasks.Win32, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
   Task "CL"
     Forcing recompile of all source files due to missing PDB "Debug\vc100.pdb".
     Environment Variables passed to tool:
       VS_UNICODE_OUTPUT=1328
     c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\CL.exe /c /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _DEBUG /D _CONSOLE /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:prompt main.cpp
     Tracking command:
     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\Tracker.exe /d C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\FileTracker.dll /i C:\projects\cpp\TestGetLine\TestGetline\Debug /r C:\PROJECTS\CPP\TESTGETLINE\TESTGETLINE\MAIN.CPP /b MSBuildConsole_CancelEvent7f4b09d9e64d472facf5c417755b2cdd  /c "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\CL.exe"  /c /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _DEBUG /D _CONSOLE /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:prompt main.cpp
     main.cpp
 1>main.cpp : fatal error C1033: cannot open program database ''
     The command exited with code 2.
   Done executing task "CL" -- FAILED.
 1>Done building target "ClCompile" in project "TestGetline.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
 1>Done Building Project "C:\projects\cpp\TestGetLine\TestGetline\TestGetline.vcxproj" (build target(s)) -- FAILED.
```

Comment: `;` missing after class definition.

Comment: I made the correction. Still the same thing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920035/visual-studio-2010-project-on-shared-folder-fatal-error-c1033-cannot-open-prog << is this of any use?

Comment: Not related to your problem but [main always returns an int](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-main)

Comment: @mattp: I corrected again the program and I made sure it compiles with gcc.

Comment: @Jekyll: Yes, I tried the suggestions in the two answers and they didn't work. My project is on the C drive of the VM, it's in a folder C:\projects\cpp\TestGetline directory. Haven't tried the SMB File sharing idea though. I will give it a try tonight.

Comment: Is the error literally `1>CL : fatal error C1033: cannot open program database ''`? Nothing between the two quotes? Also, is your source on the host or the VM?

Comment: @dauphic: I updated the message with the exact output copied & pasted from the output window. The source code is the VM in the C:\projects\cpp\TestGetline folder. And yes, there is nothing between quotes.

Comment: Go to your project's properties and Linker -> Debugging and check `Generate Program Database File`. It may be empty.

Comment: @dauphic: It was not empty. It was set to: $(TargetDir)$(TargetName).pdb. I also changed it to a hard-coded file name and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: It seems like something is wrong with your installation. I develop in the same environment (VS2010 on OS X with Windows hosted in Parallels) without problem, so it shouldn't be a VS2010/Parallels compatibility problem.

Comment: I tried to do the same on a colleague's windows laptop (windows 7 64 bit Ultimate) and we got the same error as mine. Do you run Windows 7 64 bit in your VM? Also, are you running the same version of VS 2010 as mine? Thanks

Comment: I don't suppose the volume you're sharing is case-*sensitive* on the OS X side ?

Comment: @WhozCraig: It is not. Didn't think of it before and I just tried some commands to test it on the OSX side and it's not.

Comment: If it helps anyone : I had the same problem just now (on Windows 7, with VS 2008), and it seemed to have been because I had a COMMAND PROMPT open in to the same folder as the Project folder, and had tried some command line (CMake) builds, at the same time as a VS 2008 IDE based build (in sequence, not in parallel). So, the .PDB file has been locked by the command prompt, and hence, unavialable to the IDE's build process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I unchecked the 'Run this program in compatibility mode for Windows XP (Service Pack 3)' checkbox and it works now. Originally I played with the other options but not this one !

Answer (score 16):

To solve this problem, I deleted the pdb file (after I backed it up), then builded it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is a professional Q & A site. Please visit [answer].

Comment: @afzalex If the solution is simple, there's no reason why the answer cannot be simple. There's zero need for that kind of elitism.

Comment: I had the same problem when building aseprite from github. Deleting the pdb did the trick.

Answer (score 7):

I get this error all the time when I am running a project in my dropbox folder. It seems that dropbox is backing up the .pdb file at the time I'm trying to build.

Usually it works after one or two tries.

Comment: Worked! my project is in Dropbox. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into the problem and it was because of space issues on the drive.  When I cleaned out the directory everything built fine.

[Edit] Space was a red herring.  It works out that the problem is random.  It seems that when building many files VS2010 does not free the vc100.pdb file quickly.  We placed a 1 sec wait between successive compiles and that helped most people. Some had to increase the wait to 3 seconds.  It seems MS fixed this problem in VS2012, so if you have the option to upgrade that probably best.

Comment: This answer is the only one that is anywhere near relevant to the 'why' question the OP asked. If I may ask, how did you place the waits between compiles?

Answer (score 1):

I also had this proplem

> filename.cpp: fatal error C1051: program database file, 'e:\a\b\c\d\filename.pdb

I have solved this problem by deleting `filename.pdb` file and it works.

After deleting it will Automatic generate ***.pdb** file by building and  also call that file

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not debugging while trying to build. That solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by moving the project folder to another folder. Then the compiler did not complain about it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue but in Visual Studio 2005. Cancelling a build before it had finished caused the file to become corrupt, deleting the .idb file then re-building fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, in new Windows enviroments, the paths can be case sensitive, but cl.exe cannot use them, so you need to check it and change to case insensitive. The problem is described here in spanish:

- [Cl.exe y Case Sentitivity en Windows (*.cpp: error C1033: cannot open program database '*.pdb')](https://programmersexception.blogspot.com/2019/03/clexe-y-case-sentitivity-en-windows-cpp.html)

Answer (score 0):

I also unchecked the 'Run this program in compatibility mode for Windows XP (Service Pack 3)' checkbox and it really works now. Originally I played with the other options but not this one !