# Error accessing program database in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I accidentally allowed an infinite loop, the computer froze, I force-restarted it. Now when I press F5 to build my C++ project, I get the following error:

```
Error   C1301   error accessing program database C:\path\x64\Release\projectName.ipdb, invalid format, please delete and rebuild
```

And the said file does not even exist. I tried deleting everything in the Release folder, no luck.

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try renaming the Release folder. And if that doesn't work - machine restart usually helps :)

Comment: @Rostislav thanks. I renamed Release folder, it created another Release, again not containing the *.ipdb file. Should it contain it? Anyway, let me try another restart.

Comment: That is surprising to be honest. Usually it's some screw-up with file access rights. And sometimes the renaming lets you avoid these problems without restart. However, I've never seen such troubles persisting through a restart. Perhaps restart and 'rebuild project' would help. If not - well, I'd delete the build directory and regenerate the project with CMake - but if it's not a CMake project - I have no further ideas :/ Good luck!

Comment: I don't know how to use CMake :) So I don't think it is. It is just a Win32 console application with c++. And the problem remains after restart and rebuild..

Comment: Well, I hope someone else will be able to help you :) And CMake is a very nice tool - so it's worth learning about it in the long run.

Comment: `Visual Studio 6.0
error accessing program database filename, invalid format, please delete and rebuild
This error is not used.`


Whoa, which visual studio are you using?

Comment: Also, see here about some notes regarding antivirus stuff: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126751/compilation-fails-randomly-cannot-open-program-database

Comment: It is Visual Studio 2015 Community edition.

Comment: This is severely weird... I'd try repairing the installation if the VS installer supports it. Something went terribly wrong it seems. Does any other project compile fine?

Comment: I'm not sure but I worked around the problem simply by creating a new project, and copy pasting the contents of my .cpp and .h files. Luckily I had few of them.

Comment: Wait, how did you see the `Visual Studio 6.0` part? :D

Comment: just googling the error message :) And what you did is pretty similar to regenerating project with CMake. Good that you figured it out in the end!

Comment: for me it helped to clean the project (in all configurations and targets!)

Answer (score 2):

I was also faced similar type of error which says :-

> **"C1300 Error accessing program database...  LNK1257 code generation failed"**

Resolved it in the following way:

> **Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->General->Whole Program Optimization**

set it to

> **"No Whole Program Optimization"**

from "Use Link time Code Generation"

Answer (score 0):

Mine persisted even after restart. Just rename the main file (the .sln) or compile in debugger mode. I'm not sure what the difference is but debugged .exe seem to come out as larger, so there must be a difference.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35507205)